# Google Sheet script - send an email reminder based on due date

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, gmail

I've looked around and have bits and pieces but can't put the puzzle together. I'm attempting to create a script that will send an email depending on the date. I.E. if a "response" is due on 08/30 it will send a response 2 weeks prior, 1 week prior, and the date of.

Basically I'm looking for the script to capture a range of cells, identify a due date, which will be populated in a column, match it to the current date and send out reminder emails.

The script runs but it will not send me an email.

Here is the code:

```
function emailAlert() {
  // today's date information
  var today = new Date();
  var todayMonth = today.getMonth() + 1;
  var todayDay = today.getDate();
  var todayYear = today.getFullYear();

  // 1 week from now
  var oneWeekFromToday = new Date();
  oneWeekFromToday.setDate(oneWeekFromToday.getDate() + 14);
  var oneWeekMonth = oneWeekFromToday.getMonth() + 1;
  var oneWeekDay = oneWeekFromToday.getDate();
  var oneWeekYear = oneWeekFromToday.getFullYear();
  
   // 2 weeks from now
  var twoWeeksFromToday = new Date();
  twoWeeksFromToday.setDate(twoWeeksFromToday.getDate() + 14);
  var twoWeeksMonth = twoWeeksFromToday.getMonth() + 1;
  var twoWeeksDay = twoWeeksFromToday.getDate();
  var twoWeeksYear = twoWeeksFromToday.getFullYear();

  // getting data from spreadsheet
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var startRow = 2; // First row of data to process
  var numRows = 100; // Number of rows to process

  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 999);
  var data = dataRange.getValues();

  //looping through all of the rows
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
    var row = data[i];

    var expireDateFormat = Utilities.formatDate(
      new Date(row[6]),
      'ET',
      'MM/dd/yyyy'
    );

    // email information
    var subject = '';
    var message =
      ' A grievance ' +
      '\n' +
      ' Name: ' +
      row[0] +
      '\n' +
      ' Grievance ID: ' +
      row[2] +
      '\n' +
      ' College: ' +
      row[5] +
      '\n' +
      ' Department: ' +
      row[6] +
      '\n' +
      ' Article/Policy Violation: ' +
      row[7] +
      '\n' +
      ' Status: ' +
      row[9] +
      '\n' +
      ' Response Due Date: ' +
      expireDateFormat;

    //expiration date information
    var expireDateMonth = new Date(row[12]).getMonth() + 1;
    var expireDateDay = new Date(row[12]).getDate();
    var expireDateYear = new Date(row[12]).getFullYear();

    //checking for today
    if (
      expireDateMonth === todayMonth &&
      expireDateDay === todayDay &&
      expireDateYear === todayYear
    ) {
      var subject =
        'A Grievance Is Due Today: ' + row[7] + ' - ' + expireDateFormat;
      MailApp.sendEmail('myemail.mail', subject, message);
      Logger.log('todayyyy!');
    }

    //checking for 1 week from now

    Logger.log('1 week month, expire month' + oneWeekMonth + expireDateMonth);
    if (
      expireDateMonth === oneWeekMonth &&
      expireDateDay === oneWeekDay &&
      expireDateYear === oneWeekYear
    ) {
      var subject =
        'A grievance is due in 1 week: ' +
        row[7] +
        ' - ' +
        expireDateFormat;
      MailApp.sendEmail('myemail.mail', subject, message);
      Logger.log('1 week from now');
    }

    //checking for 2 weeks from now

    Logger.log('2 weeks month, expire month' + twoWeeksMonth + expireDateMonth);
    if (
      expireDateMonth === twoWeeksMonth &&
      expireDateDay === twoWeeksDay &&
      expireDateYear === twoWeeksYear
    ) {
      var subject =
        'A grievance is due in 2 weeks: ' +
        row[7] +
        ' - ' +
        expireDateFormat;
      MailApp.sendEmail('myemail.mail', subject, message);
      Logger.log('2 weeks from now');
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand `I.E. if a "response" is due on 08/30 it will send a response 2 weeks prior, 1 week prior, and the date of.`. Can I ask you about the detail of your goal? About `The script runs but it will not send me an email.`, in your situation, how do you run your script?

Comment: Thank you for your comment, if there is a project due on 08/30, I would want an email reminder 2 weeks prior to 8/30, 1 week prior to 8/30, and an email on 08/30. In Google Sheets, you can click Extensions, Apps Script, and then I can run my code. I also ran it through a Javascript IDE and it ran without any bugs. Let me know if that answers your question